# How to unlock the "El Commandante" mission in Ghost Recon Wildlands?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I bought Ghost Recon Wildlands 1 or 2 months ago, and I finished the game, but I've heard of another enemy in the Media Luna region. This enemy is El Commandante, I know that you had to play the beta to get it as a "bonus" enemy, but is there another way to unlock it? I would like a method that is free (if possible) and that works on Xbox One S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a reward for playing the alpha or beta for Wildlands, playing the full game any time before March 31, you'll receive a free extra set of missions. Known as UNIDAD Conspiracy Missions. These ones focus on hunting down a leader of the Unidad faction called El Comandante.

Now the only other way of getting it, is by spending money on the season pass.

The season pass opens up the UNIDAD Missions, without previously playing the Betas.